# MariaDB Create Procedure Error 1064 Syntax

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I am getting a syntax error (1064) at line 10 ''. The line 10 is the line with the FROM.
I tried without delimiter. I tried adding ";" after the "stg_mytable". I tried with just "SELECT 1 as cname" in the stored procedure body. I tried in the UI of HeidiSQL instead of commands.
Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE MySP()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo_mytable
(ColumnStr, OtherColumn)
 SELECT ColumnStr, OtherColumn
 FROM stg_mytable

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error when I add `;` after `FROM stg_mytable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, HeidiSQL and DBeaver have difficulties with delimiters. I have successfully created my stored procedure in MySQL Workbench.